# How to display dual language menus and headers?

Tags: php, multi-language, theme-twenty-seventeen

For reference: https://www.hpa.org.nz/about/our-role

Note the dual language menu - Te Reo Māori in smaller text above each English menu item and the English header.

All the multi-lang plugins I have looked at allow language switching but I just want two languages to be displayed on the menus and headers at once.

The current theme used is Twenty Seventeen and I can achieve this with some quick and dirty css (::before pseudo element)

e.g.

```
.menu-item::before {
  content: "Menu item";
}

h2::before {
  content: "Header item";
  font-family: "Libre Franklin";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 0.65em;
  display: block;
}
```

But that requires me to add in relevant css for each and every menu item, header and anywhere else I want to use dual language.

So is there a way to have a multilanguage plugin plus a PHP (or javacript maybe?) code snippet that will pull in the other language as a ::before ?

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to use menu descriptions (option found in Menus Screen Options, if not enabled yet) and a [custom menu walker](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker) to display extra text before/after menu items in similar fashion as in the reference site you mentioned. This way you could add the translated string to the menu description field.

[WPBeginner](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-menu-descriptions-in-your-wordpress-themes/) has posted an example how to display menu description with a custom walker. For future reference here's the code. I modified the example so that the description is before the menu item text.

```
// This goes into your child theme functions.php
class Menu_With_Description extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
        $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

        $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';

        $attributes = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target ) ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn ) ? ' rel="' . esc_attr( $item->xfn ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url ) ? ' href="' . esc_attr( $item->url ) .'"' : '';

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= '<span class="sub">' . $item->description . '</span><br>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

As you're using Twenty Seventeen you need to copy `components/navigation/navigation-top.php` file to similar path in your child theme.

Then add the custom walker to the menu. Like so,

```
<?php
/**
 * Displays top navigation with custom walker
 */
?>
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation" aria-label="<?php _e( 'Top Menu', 'twentyseventeen' ); ?>">
    <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="top-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php echo twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'bars' ) ); echo twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'close' ) ); _e( 'Menu', 'twentyseventeen' ); ?></button>
    <?php 
    $walker = new Menu_With_Description;
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location' => 'top',
        'menu_id'        => 'top-menu',
        'walker'        => $walker, // Add custom walker to the menu
    ) ); ?>

    <?php if ( twentyseventeen_is_frontpage() || ( is_home() && is_front_page() ) ) : ?>
        <a href="#content" class="menu-scroll-down"><?php echo twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'next' ) ); ?><span class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Scroll Down', 'twentyseventeen' ); ?></span></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
</nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
```

Then add the necessary styling to your child themes `styles.css`.